# Alpha threshold for object index layer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, masking

[EDITED]
Using cycle mode, I am trying to get a mask image of the rendered object which object index layer.

But when compared with the "composite" layer, "object index" layer does not seem to mask the rendered object correctly.

e.g.

Combined layer
[image]

Object Index layer
[image]

I set [Alpha Threshold](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html#cycles) to 0 but there is no effect.

How can I get a mask image covering the combined layer correctly for any pixel with alpha > 0?

Comment: Why don't you multiply the object pass with the alpha pass ?

Comment: @Gorgious What do you mean? Multiplying alpha channel of combined layer to the object pass layer?

Comment: Yes, and set a Greater than to filter out the threshold at which you don't want the object pass to appear. Blender doesn't know whether you want alpha between 0 and 1 to be considered as object pass or not

Answer (score 0):

It's prolly 'cause of Cycles render. Try to increase noise threshold also amount of samples and turn off denoise

[image: render properties].

Also, keep in mind how Cycles render works, and you might consider using Eveee for that kind of thing.
In addition, try to increase light paths value like about 2x times and see what happens.
[image: light paths properties]